# Is this use case suitable for project-reactor?

Tags: java, project-reactor

I'm starting to dive into project reactor in order to understand if it fits my user case, but I'm not sure it is the case.
My user case is a bit complicated:

Application A can send some messages to Application B via http
Each message is an operation on a document (Ex. insert doc1, delete doc1)
Application B receives the messages, do some operation (mainly checks on the content) and if all is ok it forwards the message to Application C. If application C responds OK Application B notifies A (using an http call) that the message has been sent to C.

Application C is outside my control

Application B is what I must implement; it have some additional requirements

Application B must be asyncronous with respect to A; i.e. A must not wait that B sends the message to C.

If B sends a insert message on document D1 and it receives a delete message on document D1 from A, the delete message must wait the execution of the insertion and only after the execution is successful B can send the deletion message. If the  insertion message of D1 to C gets a timeout, the message must be rescheduled and the cancellation message must be queued after the successful insertion. If the insertion message faces more then n timeouts both the insertion and delete messages must be save for later offline processing. Application A guarantees that insertion and delete message are sent to B in the right order.

B must allow for concurrent executions, i.e a message that operates on document D1 must not block messages that operate on message with a different id (i.e. D2).

At the moment I'm planning to use a Queue in application B, when a message arrives it is put in the queue and processed later. My toughts were to develop a reactive application (using spring project-reactor) that manages (inside application B) the communication with C, but I'm stuck with error handling and retries attempt.

Can someone tell me if this is a suitalbe use case for project reactor? and if it is can someone give me some concrete suggestion for handling my requirements?

Thanks a lot